# Conditional IF statement inside this.state of the Constructor Reactjs

Tags: reactjs

Im trying to render a conditional if inside a state variable of my constructor.

**My original code is like this and it works**

```
constructor(props, context){
  super(props, context);
}
this.state={
  ... // the rest of my state 
  columns: [{
    render:          
      row => (
        row.row.exported === 0 ?

        <span className={styles.centered} >
        {
          row.value === true ? <img src={checkedImage} />
              : <img src={uncheckedImage} />
        }
      </span>: ""
    ),
    maxWidth: 60,
    hideFilter: true,
    style: {textAlign:"center"},
  }]
}
```

**And i want to do something like this:**

```
    constructor(props, context){
      super(props, context);

    this.state={
      ... // the rest of my state 
      columns:             
        render:
          if(this.state.profile.role == 'dba' || this.state.profile.role == 'both'){
            row => (
            row.row.exported === 0 ?
            <span className={styles.centered} >
              {
                row.value === true ? <img src={checkedImage} />
                    : <img src={uncheckedImage} />
              }
            </span>: ""
          }
        ),   
        maxWidth: 60,
        hideFilter: true,
        style: {textAlign:"center"},
      }]
    }
  }
```

In my render method im using **react-table** so it look like this:

**Render Method**

```
render(){
 return(
  <ReactTable columns={this.state.columns} />
 )
}
```

Is it possible or is there any work around to achieve this?

Comment: Why do you keep jsx in state... Shouldn't state just keep pure data?

Comment: you may use renderif for conditional rendering

Comment: @wesley6j Im new to React, how would I do that?

Comment: @user2906608 Is it possible to use renderif inside this.state?

Comment: Can you show the render method as well ?

Comment: I've updated the code with the render method @G4bri3l

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pull the if statement inside of your callback and give your callback a body. Then you can use the appropriate conditionals.  A quick fix would have a form that looked something a little like this:

```
render: (row) => {
  if(this.state.profile.role == 'dba' || this.state.profile.role == 'both'){
    return (
    row.row.exported === 0 ?
    <span className={styles.centered} >
      {
        row.value === true ? <img src={checkedImage} />
            : <img src={uncheckedImage} />
      }
    </span>: ""
  }
),
```

}
Since you have a function body you can use either the ternary operator or if statements for control flow.

Personally, this looks a little messy and the whole definition is deeply nested in an object literal so Id define a function somewhere outside:

```
const rowRender = (row) => { ...the code above... }

columns:             
        render: (row) => rowRender(row),
        maxWidth: 60,
        hideFilter: true,
        style: {textAlign:"center"},
      }]
```

Comment: Thanks for the complete answer and I know if have a mess on my code. I will try to refactor my code. Your answer actually solved my problem!

Answer (score 1):

It's a little hard to understand what you are trying to do, this is a significant signal that your code needs improvement. A good alternative would be to have columns being their own components with a render method a state and all.

You can pass down props from the current component and then do conditional rendering from inside the current component and from inside the `column` component as well. I am wildly guessing here but your component can be kind of like this:

```
...
render() {
  return() {
    ...
    {
      this.state.profile.role === 'dba' || this.state.profile.role === 'both'
        ? (
         <Column
           row={this.props.row}
           checkedImage={checkedImage}
           uncheckedImage={uncheckedImage}
           ... // other props
         />
       )
       : null
     }
     ...
   }
 }
 ...
```

So what I am doing here I am conditionally rendering the column depending on the state of my component (instead of a ternary you can also just use `&&`). Now inside the `Column`:

```
...
render() {
  return() {
    this.props.row.exported === 0
      ? (
        <span className={styles.centered} >
          {
            this.props.row.value === true
              ? <img src={this.props.checkedImage} />
              : <img src={this.props.uncheckedImage} />
          }
        </span>
      )
      : null
   }
 }
 ...
```

This is much more clear and also allows you to easily modify your `Column` component and its rendering logic.

**EDIT**

Given the edit on your question you can also alter the columns you are passing down with a `.filter`. In this case your render method would be like this:

```
render() {
  const columns = this.state.columns.filter(column => {
    return (this.state.profile.role === 'dba' || this.state.profile.role === 'both');
  }

  return() {
    <ReactTable columns={columns} />
  }
}
```

If you are not familiar with js `filter` check some docs [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter?v=control).